# i was trying to install some packages to my react project i got this " found 1 low severity vulnerability" ,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[and here is my terminal which describes my error clearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7v15.jpg)

> i was trying to install some packages to my react project, and I got this " found 1 low severity vulnerability" , so I did run `npm audit` and I found the problem in react-scripts dependencies, so I ran npm install react-scripts --save, but that didn't solve the problem and still have the same error
>   " found 1 low severity vulnerability"

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm audit fix`, that should fix the issue. If that doesn't work, delete your `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` file then try again.

You could also try `npm update`.

Comment: i did run `npm audit fix`  and that what i have in the terminal now fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 931989 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated

Comment: Delete your `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` and try again

Comment: I deleted `package-lock.json` then i ran `npm install` but nothing has changed

Comment: What I meant is deleting the package-lock then running `npm audit fix`